# Get @HostListener to wait before starting

Tags: angular

I'm using @HostListener scroll event for angular, and I'm hoping to find a way that I can get it to wait 3 seconds before it does anything, but only the first time it is triggered

```
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event']) getScrollHeight(event) {

  const numberWhenItEntersViewport =
    document.getElementById("innerScreenSection").offsetTop -
    document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  const yValueBottomOfElement =
    document.getElementById("innerScreenSection").offsetTop +
    document.getElementById("innerScreenSection").offsetHeight;
  const elementHeight = document.getElementById("innerScreenSection")
    .offsetHeight;

  // if the element is where I want it and the timer has not gone yet then start the timer
  // I realize I never declare waitedThreeSeconds, this is just for show of what I'm thinking
  if (
    waitedThreeSeconds === false &&
    window.pageYOffset >= numberWhenItEntersViewport + 0.25 * elementHeight &&
    window.pageYOffset <= yValueBottomOfElement - 0.3 * elementHeight
  ) {
    // start timer and set waitedThreeSeconds to true? Idk how to do this without declaring
    // a varible in here and having it turned back to false everytime this function is called
    // it also does not seem to be able to read variables outside of this function
    // specifically when they change it doesnt update
  } else {
    // 3 seconds have passed
    console.log("scrolling and 3 seconds have passed");
  }
}
```

Comment: You can create a wrapper function which have setTimeout method, inside setTimeout  you may call to your function, where you can specify the time limit. in your case 3 second.

Comment: I've tried that, but you can't put `@HostListener` inside another function and have it run on scroll. I've also tried making a setTimeout function outside of the `@HostListener` and have it change a variable to true after 3 seconds, but that variable does not update inside the `@HostListener`

Comment: `@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event']) getScrollHeight(event) { setTimeout(() => { your logic }, 3000); }`  - Have you tried like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
    import { Subject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
    import { delay, concatMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

    // Delay amount (ms)
    const DELAY = 3000;
```

...

```js
    // Setup
    private readonly eventStream = new Subject<Event>();

    // On the first emission, delay.
    // After the delay, REMAP to the original stream (concatMap)
    // USE first() to complete outer observable.
    get eventStream$(): Observable<Event> {
      return this.eventStream.pipe(
        delay(DELAY),
        first(),
        concatMap(() => this.eventStream)
      );
    }

      // Listen to clicks and emit
      @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event']) scroll(event: Event) {
        this.eventStream.next(event);
      }

      constructor() {
        this.eventStream$.subscribe(this.isScroll);
      }

      isScroll(event: Event) {
        // Do math here.
        console.log(event);
      }

      ngOnDestroy() {
        // Cleanup.
        this.eventStream.unsubscribe();
      }
```

Now we could proceed to throttle responses etc.

Comment: Hi Brad, this works to not let it run for 3 seconds, but I want that to be the case just for when the page loads, then I want it to run instantly as many times as someone scrolls. How would I get this to disable itself after running once?

Comment: @RyanSoderberg I'm sorry I completely misread the question! I will update it.

Comment: @RyanSoderberg Updated the question.

Comment: Hey @BradAxe, sorry to ask another question, but is there a way to wrap the `get` in a conditional statement, so the timer doesn't start let's say until a button is clicked?

Comment: @RyanSoderberg What happens if you click the button again?

Comment: Nothing, so maybe the button changes a value to true when clicked that is default false, and as many times the button is clicked the value will remain true

Comment: @RyanSoderberg although using a switch may work, since we are working with data streams I like to keep it consistent if you choose to use this approach.  We just need another stream for the click events and to move some of the same bits around.  Anyway, I made a stackblitz describing both.  Hope this helps https://stackblitz.com/github/baxelson12/ng-host-listener

Comment: You're a lifesaver! I donated $5 to Girls Who Code on your behalf https://imgur.com/zDJLf0f thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

You may try something like below snippet. Hope it may help you.

```
 timeOutId:number;
    @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event']) getScrollHeight(event) { 
    clearTimeout(this.timeOutId);
    this.timeoutId = setTimeout(() => { 
       // call your method 
    }, 3000); 
 }
```